# Update the value of parent all the way till the tree based on key

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, ecmascript-6

I have an array of object that look this,

```
const data = [
  {
    "key": "group1",
    "name": "groupname1",
    "total": 65,
    "available": 34,
    "children": [
      {
        "key": "cat1",
        "name": "category1",
        "total": 5,
        "available": 2,
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "key": "cat2",
        "name": "category2",
        "total": 60,
        "available": 32,
        "children": [
          {
            "key": "cat3",
            "name": "category3",
            "total": 15,
            "available": 12,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "key": "cat6",
            "name": "category6",
            "total": 55,
            "available": 20,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "group2",
    "name": "groupname2",
    "total": 75,
    "available": 47,
    "children": [
      {
        "key": "cat4",
        "name": "category4",
        "total": 25,
        "available": 22,
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "key": "cat5",
        "name": "category5",
        "total": 50,
        "available": 25,
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

key property at each level is unique across the entire tree. When I pass in key as a paremeter and this array to a functon, it should increment the `available` value at the matching key level and this increment should go all the way upto root.So basically when I pass incrementRecursively(data, "cat3"), the output should look like,

```
[
  {
    "key": "group1",
    "name": "groupname1",
    "total": 65,
    "available": 35,
    "children": [
      {
        "key": "cat1",
        "name": "category1",
        "total": 5,
        "available": 2,
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "key": "cat2",
        "name": "category2",
        "total": 60,
        "available": 33,
        "children": [
          {
            "key": "cat3",
            "name": "category3",
            "total": 15,
            "available": 13,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "key": "cat6",
            "name": "category6",
            "total": 55,
            "available": 20,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "group2",
    "name": "groupname2",
    "total": 75,
    "available": 47,
    "children": [
      {
        "key": "cat4",
        "name": "category4",
        "total": 25,
        "available": 22,
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "key": "cat5",
        "name": "category5",
        "total": 50,
        "available": 25,
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I track the parent and update the increments all the way to the root node? Code I tried that doesnt work

```
function increment(nodes, key, depth = 0) {
  for (let n of nodes) {
    const nodeOwnKeyMatches = n.key === key;
    const nodeChildsKeyMatches = increment(n.children, key, depth + 1);
    if (!nodeOwnKeyMatches && !nodeChildsKeyMatches) continue;
    if (nodeOwnKeyMatches) n.available++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `return nodeOwnKeyMatches || nodeChildsKeyMatches;` at the end.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, Tried, that doesnt seem like working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do it: For each node, check if there is a key match or if one of its children is a key match (recursively). If so, increment the `available` property of the node and return `true` to indicate that a match was found.

```js
const data = [{"key":"group1","name":"groupname1","total":65,"available":34,"children":[{"key":"cat1","name":"category1","total":5,"available":2,"children":[]},{"key":"cat2","name":"category2","total":60,"available":32,"children":[{"key":"cat3","name":"category3","total":15,"available":12,"children":[]},{"key":"cat6","name":"category6","total":55,"available":20,"children":[]}]}]},{"key":"group2","name":"groupname2","total":75,"available":47,"children":[{"key":"cat4","name":"category4","total":25,"available":22,"children":[]},{"key":"cat5","name":"category5","total":50,"available":25,"children":[]}]}]

function increment(node, key) {
  return (node.key===key || node.children.some(c=>increment(c, key))) 
    && (node.available++, true)
}

data.forEach(n=>increment(n, 'cat3'))
console.log(data)
```

As per the comment below, to prevent top-level nodes being incremented as a result of descendent key matches:

```js
const data = [{"key":"group1","name":"groupname1","total":65,"available":34,"children":[{"key":"cat1","name":"category1","total":5,"available":2,"children":[]},{"key":"cat2","name":"category2","total":60,"available":32,"children":[{"key":"cat3","name":"category3","total":15,"available":12,"children":[]},{"key":"cat6","name":"category6","total":55,"available":20,"children":[]}]}]},{"key":"group2","name":"groupname2","total":75,"available":47,"children":[{"key":"cat4","name":"category4","total":25,"available":22,"children":[]},{"key":"cat5","name":"category5","total":50,"available":25,"children":[]}]}]

function increment(node, key, isTopLevel) {
  return (node.key===key || node.children.some(c=>increment(c, key)))
    && (!isTopLevel && node.available++, true)
}

data.forEach(n=>increment(n, 'cat3', true))
console.log(data)
```

Comment: @lrr59 I just changed it so that it works on a particular node, instead of a list of them. It's now simpler. The `available` property of parents should be updated.

Comment: small update. In case i want all the nodes to be updated except for the root node, what can be done?May be keep the first edit and add one more edit, it really helps

Comment: @lrr59 but what if the key is `group1`? Should it then do nothing? (Perhaps you will never specify any top-level keys?)

Comment: Imagine the second version doesn't take any root keys as input. Only non root keys are passed

Comment: @lrr59 I added it in

Answer (score 1):

The result is also possible to achieve with a help of Map and a little addition to the structure of the original tree.

```js
let rootBranch = [
  {
    "key": "group1",
    "name": "groupname1",
    "total": 65,
    "available": 35,
    "children": [
      {
        "key": "cat1",
        "name": "category1",
        "total": 5,
        "available": 2,
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "key": "cat2",
        "name": "category2",
        "total": 60,
        "available": 33,
        "children": [
          {
            "key": "cat3",
            "name": "category3",
            "total": 15,
            "available": 13,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "key": "cat6",
            "name": "category6",
            "total": 55,
            "available": 20,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "group2",
    "name": "groupname2",
    "total": 75,
    "available": 47,
    "children": [
      {
        "key": "cat4",
        "name": "category4",
        "total": 25,
        "available": 22,
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "key": "cat5",
        "name": "category5",
        "total": 50,
        "available": 25,
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
];

function prepareForBubbling (rootBranch) {
    let map = new Map();
    function mapChildren (parent) {
        parent.children.forEach((child) => {
            child.parent = parent;
            map.set(child.key, child);
            mapChildren(child);
        });
    }
    rootBranch.forEach((child) => {
        child.parent = null;
        map.set(child.key, child);
        mapChildren(child);
    });
    return map;
}

function bubbleUp (map, key, callback) {
    let nodesProcessed = 0;
    let node = map.get(key);
    let userValue;
    while (node) {
        userValue = callback(node, userValue);
        nodesProcessed++;
        node = node.parent;
    }
    return nodesProcessed;
}

let nodeMap = prepareForBubbling(rootBranch);

// test only nodes without children to make the result easier to visually check
['cat1', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5', 'cat6']
.forEach((key) => bubbleUp(nodeMap, key, (node) => node.available++));
console.log(rootBranch);
```

```
Nesting levels:  0                   0
                     1   1               1   1
                             2   2

Initial values:  35  2   33  13  20  47  22  25
Updated values:  38  3   35  14  21  49  23  26
```